# AntD horizontal collapse

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to make a horizontal collapse  (like a sider) instead a vertical one.

I'm tried with the Layout component but no results.

Is there any way to use the Collapse or Panel component from AntD but vertically instead of horizontal?
So when I click it, it expands from left to right instead of top to bottom?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Drawer but rendered within the DOM
It's not the exact same but works nicely.

https://ant.design/components/drawer/#components-drawer-demo-render-in-current
https://codesandbox.io/s/z00q1e

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32693348)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's super close to what I want but not quite since it is modal. I ended up using other libraries such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-collapse-pane

Apologies for not being clear that I wanted non-modal.